# Call wp-blog-header.php header without performing a wp_query

Tags: loop, themes

I have setup .htaccess to map a custom url to a custom php script. This page is not part of wordpress, but i want it to use the wordpress theme. At the top of the script I load up Wordpress. And from here i populate the global $post object with my own custom data.

```
require_once('../wp-blog-header.php');
//change status to 200 from 404
//custom code to get data and populate the $post
include get_template_directory()."/page.php";
```

This works great in a web browser, but in some exceptions it causes problems. For example if i have a blog post in wordpress with a slug of `/some-post` and i have a custom page with a url of site.com/somethingelse. Wordpress generates a 301 redirect to `/some-post`. This occurs in the require_once, which means i cannot override it. It happens as soon as a call the wp-blog-header.php script. This means that google does not index this page correctly. Is there a way i can call the theme without wordpress redirecting or doing anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the WordPress framework without the querying, use `wp-load.php`:

```
require '/path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php';
```

Comment: This is perfect. I wish I had of asked this question a year ago!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will be suitable to your case but you can try:

```
define('SHORTINIT',true);
```

before including `wp-blog-header.php` and many things will not load - perhaps the redirect will be one of them?

(But, it does mean you may have to include a lot of `wp-includes` files manually too for many of the WordPress functions to be able to run without fatal errors.)